# python how to include a file of lists in a script

Tags: python

I have a file that gets generated by :

excerpt:

```
group0 = ['ParentPom']

group1 = ['Commons','http', 'availability','ingestPom','abcCommons','solrIndex','123Service']

...

group10=['totalCommons','Generator']
```

How can I include this in my python script, tried import but no luck

```
>>> import dependencies_custom
>>> print (group2[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'group2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `import` form you're using, you should be able to access the groups by

```
dependencies_custom.group2[0]
```

type notation. If you want just use just `group2[0]` notation, try using:

```
from dependencies_custom import *
```